# Optimize loading of remote plist

Tags: iphone, load, plist, minimize

I have written an application which loads information from a plist which lies on my server (I hope this is OK with Apple :-)). The application runs smooth on WiFi but when using it on 3G the load times are a little too long. Therefore I would like to optimize the loading of my plist.

I imagine that I could store a copy of the plist on the device and only check if the remote plist has changed and if so, download it. I am not sure if this will be less data and therefore minimize the load time and I'm not even sure how this would be written in code.

Does anyone have an idea how I can minimize the loadtime and possibly post a code sample?

Right now I am using these two lines to load the plist and store it. `FETCH_URL` is obviously my URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:FETCH_URL];
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

**EDIT:** I am trying to use NSURLConnection as Thomas Clayson suggests but I can't seem to figure out how to convert the data into an NSMutableArray.

This is in my viewDidLoad:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FETCH_URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        NSLog(@"Connection open.");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed connecting.");
    }
```

Then I have these two methods to check if there is any new data and to check if all data has been collection.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"More data.");
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Connection successful.");
}
```

Comment: Are load times the problem or is the app hanging while you're loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you mean. You will want to use NSURLConnnection instead of `initWithContentsOfURL`.

initWithContentsOfURL is synchronous. That means that it will run on the main thread and thus "hang" the application (this is because UI events have to occur on the main thread and if a process is happening (waiting for the plist to download) the app will 'stop').

Anyway - if you use NSURLConnection then you will be able to do it asynchronously (on another thread). This means that for a while your app will be usable, but won't display the data from the plist straight away. So you'll need to handle the view to refresh the data when the `connectionDidFinishLoading:`.

look it up anyway. :) its very useful

Comment: This sounds very good. I have tried reading on it in Apple's documentation. I think that I have nearly got it working but I can't seem to find out how to convert or add the data to an `NSMutableArray`. I have edited my original post to show my code. Can you help me converting the data to an NSMutableArray that I can extract it from later on?

Comment: @SimonBS When you start the connection, you should create an NSMutableData object to buffer the data. In `connection:didReceiveData:`, you would append data to that buffer. Finally, in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, you would call `+[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:options:format:error:]` (or the propertyListFromData:... variant for iOS prior to 4.0) to convert the data to a property list type (i.e., NSArray).

Comment: Would it be something like this? `NSArray *testArray = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:receivedData options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:NULL error:NULL];` it does not seem to work. It is as if `receivedData` is NULL but I do use `[receivedData appendData:data];`in `didReceiveData`

Comment: is receivedData an NSMutableData type?

Comment: Yes, it's declared in my header. `NSMutableData *receivedData;` `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *receivedData;`

Comment: I just played around with NSURLConnection and got it working (not sure what was wrong, though). Anyways. With the old code it took 11 seconds before the application was ready to use (on EDGE), now it takes 1 sec. on any network! Just gotta add a loading screen now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize load time only by minimizing the plist itself. Try various formats (binary plist, xml plist). If you have an option - try fetching json. AFAIK it has best information-to-size ratio. Binary plist parses fastest and xml plist is best for debugging purposes.

Comment: a 10mb json feed is still a 10mb json feed... this will only help cut down the size of the file, not the loading time.

Comment: Smaller size of the file means less loading time. No?

Comment: Yes - but what happens when the dataset increases in size?