# ios kmlviewer load remote url instead of local file

Tags: ios, nsstring, mkmapview

I'm using the kmlviewer example from Apple but it takes the kml file from a local diretory. What I want to do is call that file remotely using an url.

This is the original code from Apple:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"KML_Sample" ofType:@"kml"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
kmlParser = [[KMLParser alloc] initWithURL:url];
[kmlParser parseKML];
```

How can I call a remote file which is in an url as: http://www.domain.com/route.kml ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MapViewController.h** :

```
    .....
    NSMutableData   *webData;
    KMLParser       *kml;
    .....
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData   *webData;
```

**MapViewController.m** :

```
- (IBAction)showKmlData:(id)sender  //Let's say you want to download kml data with a button tap, you create a method for that (you may not act like this, but the content is the same):
{
    NSURL *path = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/route.kml"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:path];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [connection release];
    [request release];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   self.webData =[NSMutableData data];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{   
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *fileName = [[[NSURL URLWithString:kmlStr] path] lastPathComponent];
    //NSString *fileName = @"route.kml"; 
    NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *folder = [pathArr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];  
    NSError *writeError = nil;

    [webData writeToURL: fileURL options:0 error:&writeError];

    if( writeError) {
        NSLog(@" Error in writing file %@' : \n %@ ", filePath , writeError );
        return;
    }

    kml = [[KMLParser parseKMLAtPath:filePath] retain];

    NSArray *annotations = [kml points];

    if ([[mapview overlays] count] == 0) {
        [mapview addAnnotations:annotations];

        NSArray *overlays = [kml overlays];
        [mapview addOverlays:overlays];
        MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;

        for (id <MKOverlay> overlay in overlays) {
            if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
                flyTo = [overlay boundingMapRect];
            } else {
                flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, [overlay boundingMapRect]);
            }
        }

        for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
            MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
            MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
            if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
                flyTo = pointRect;
            } else {
                flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
            }
        }

        mapview.visibleMapRect = flyTo;
    }

    [mapview addAnnotations:annotations];
    NSArray *overlays = [kml overlays];
    [mapview addOverlays:overlays];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"An error has occured." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget you need to add `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>` to the .h file (for iOS 5+).

Answer (score 2):

I added an Initializer in the KMLParser to use NSData:

In the KMLParser.h file, add:

```
-(id) initWithData: (NSData *) data;
```

In the KMLParser.m file add:

```
-(id) initWithData: (NSData *)data
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _styles = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        _placemarks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

        [_xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would download the file and save it locally in either the documents or temp directory. Basic steps are:

- Create an NSURLRequest with your desired URL
- Create an NSURLConnection with that NSURLRequest
- Create an NSMutableData member variable to store the data as it is received from the NSURLConnection.
- Implement the methods for the NSURLConnection delegate:

  - connection:didReceiveResponse (make sure it was success i.e. http 200)
  - connection:didReceiveData (append the data received to your NSMutableData variable)
  - connection:didFailWithError (handle errors)
  - connectionDidFinishLoading (all data now received, write it out to a local file)

Refer to this very useful example project from Apple, where they show how to download a file and save it locally following the steps I outlined above:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html

There is also a good step by step guide in Apple's docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Then once you have the file locally, it will be trivial to open with the KMLParser using a URL to wherever you save the file to.

Comment: Although terribly documented, for iOS 5+ it should be `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, not `NSURLConnectionDelegate` (as described ambiguously in [iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Differences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Without `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` it's simple as:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/route.kml"];
kmlParser = [[KMLParser parseKMLAsURL:url] retain];

NSArray *overlays = [kmlParser overlays];
[mapView addOverlays:overlays];
```

etc. for annotations.

As for `parseKMLAtURL`, it's implemented in another version (1.1) of Apple SDK's KMLViewer as:

```
+ (KMLParser)parseKMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSXMLParser *xml = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    KMLParser *parser = [[KMLParser alloc] init];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    [xml parse];
    [parser _assignStyles];
    return [parser autorelease];
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage to this approach is that `initWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous operation, meaning that the UI will not be responsive for as long as it runs (as described in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016595/577537)).